# Can not play rtsp - Streams with Linux

Tags: rtsp

I am unable to play any rtsp Stream from XUbuntu (21.04 , 20.04) or Debian 11. I have used Live-USB-Sticks to have a fresh system too.

As software I have tried it with mplayer, vlc (3.012), ffmpeg ... but no success.

From my Android device (Tablet or Phone) I can play any stream with VLC.
From my Laptop with Windows7 I can play any steam with VLC.

Possibly this Error-Message from ffplay could help to find the problem:

```bash
~$ ffplay rtsp://192.168.178.2:8554/video
ffplay version 4.3.2-0+deb11u1ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2003-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10 (Ubuntu 10.2.1-20ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu ...

  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100

[rtsp @ 0x7f7008000bc0] method SETUP failed: 459 Client error=0/0   
rtsp://192.168.178.2:8554/video: Server returned 4XX Client Error, but not one of 40{0,1,3,4}
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
~$
```

From MPlayer:

```bash
:~$ mplayer rtsp://192.168.178.2:8554/video
MPlayer 1.4 (Debian), built with gcc-10 (C) 2000-2019 MPlayer Team
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing rtsp://192.168.178.2:8554/video.
Resolving 192.168.178.2 for AF_INET6...

Couldn't resolve name for AF_INET6: 192.168.178.2
Connecting to server 192.168.178.2[192.168.178.2]: 8554...

rtsp: warning: setting NEW session: 48863bf289524adc;timeout=60;timeout=60
Timeout! No data from host 0.0.0.0
rtsp_session: unsupported RTSP server. Server type is 'VLC/3.0.11'.
libavformat version 58.45.100 (external)
libavformat file format detected.
[rtsp @ 0x7f5acb1ba180]method SETUP failed: 459 Client error
LAVF_header: av_open_input_stream() failed


Exiting... (End of file)
```

```bash
This is the VLC Debug-Log:

dbus debug: Getting All properties
dbus debug: Getting All properties
dbus debug: Getting All properties
dbus debug: Getting All properties
main debug: processing request item: rtsp://192.168.178.2:8554/video, node: Wiedergabeliste, skip: 0
main debug: rebuilding array of current - root Wiedergabeliste
main debug: rebuild done - 2 items, index 1
main debug: starting playback of new item
main debug: resyncing on rtsp://192.168.178.2:8554/video
main debug: rtsp://192.168.178.2:8554/video is at 1
main debug: creating new input thread
main debug: Creating an input for 'rtsp://192.168.178.2:8554/video'
main debug: requesting art for new input thread
main debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
main debug: using default timeshift path
main debug: `rtsp://192.168.178.2:8554/video' gives access `rtsp' demux `any' path `192.168.178.2:8554/video'
main debug: creating demux: access='rtsp' demux='any' location='192.168.178.2:8554/video' file='(null)'
main debug: looking for access_demux module matching "rtsp": 18 candidates
main debug: no access_demux modules matched
main debug: creating access: rtsp://192.168.178.2:8554/video
main debug: looking for access module matching "rtsp": 29 candidates
main debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
satip debug: try to open 'rtsp://192.168.178.2:8554/video'
satip debug: connect to host '192.168.178.2'
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/mikropower/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
main debug: net: connecting to 192.168.178.2 port 8554
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
main debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
main debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/mikropower/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
main debug: no art finder modules matched
main debug: connection succeeded (socket = 35)
main debug: net: opening 0.0.0.0 datagram port 9156
main debug: net: opening 0.0.0.0 datagram port 9157
qt debug: IM: Setting an input
satip error: Failed to setup RTSP session
main debug: net: connecting to 192.168.178.2 port 8554
main debug: connection succeeded (socket = 34)
access_realrtsp warning: Cseq mismatch, got 1, assumed 0
access_realrtsp debug: rtsp connected
access_realrtsp warning: only real/helix rtsp servers supported for now
main debug: no access modules matched
main debug: dead input
qt debug: IM: Deleting the input
main debug: changing item without a request (current 1/2)
main debug: nothing to play
dbus debug: Getting All properties
dbus debug: Getting All properties
dbus debug: Getting All properties
```

Debug of cvlc:

```bash
...
lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
main art finder debug: no art finder modules matched
satip stream error: Failed to setup RTSP session
main stream debug: net: connecting to 192.168.178.2 port 8554
main stream debug: connection succeeded (socket = 11)
access_realrtsp stream warning: Cseq mismatch, got 1, assumed 0
access_realrtsp stream debug: rtsp connected
access_realrtsp stream warning: only real/helix rtsp servers supported for now
main stream debug: no access modules matched
main input error: Ihre Eingabe konnte nicht geöffnet werden
main input error: VLC kann die Medienadresse 'rtsp://192.168.178.2:8554' nicht öffnen. Für Details bitte im Fehlerprotokoll nachsehen.
main playlist debug: dead input
main playlist debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
main playlist debug: nothing to play
dbus interface debug: Getting All properties
dbus interface debug: Getting All properties
...
```

Comment: I have opened RTSP streams from the web browser fairly often (Firefox) on 20.04 but never tried other apps, sorry. IIRC I didn't have to do anything special with the browser, they just worked.

Comment: Maybe you need a user:password@192.... in your rtsp string.

Comment: @Kurankat - If you enter a rtsp address, then the Browser (firefox) ask to open this with an other application. In my case this is VLC.

Comment: @ubfan1 - In the source, there is no password needed. I can run VLC on my Android-phone and Android-tablet-PC, Windows-PC everything is running ... but only under XUbuntu / Debian the rtsp streams does not run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From this [Debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=982299)

> We had to disable those plugins as liblivemedia constains non-free code. See #981439. Maybe that's wort a NEWS entry and a note in the release-notes.

And from [VLC forums](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&p=520633#p520527):

> Debian VLC builds do not support RTSP by Debian policy decision"

With a VLC SNAP-package it is possible to play rtsp-Streams.

And it looks like every program (mplayer, ffplay, vlc ... ) which was build for Debian has removed the rtsp-Streaming ability too.

Comment: Did you try the [Flatpak alternative](https://www.flathub.org/apps/details/org.videolan.VLC)?

Comment: No. I have installed the SNAP-package first and it works fine, only the first start-time (after reboot) is a bit high. But I hope they fix the non-free code problem and then I can see my streams without an additional VLC-container-package.

Comment: If this bit about liblivemedia is true, then why is it that Celluloid can play my rtsp stream URLs on Mate 22.04? In any event, it has made VLC useless to me, so I've uninstalled it.